# PF2: Can alchemist poison his bombs?

Tags: weapons, pathfinder-2e, poison, alchemist

So poisons can be applied to weapons. This is typically done with poisons that have the Injury trait. Which requires the weapon to deal either piercing or slashing damage. I found 4 such bombs:

- [Junk Bomb](https://2e.aonprd.com/Equipment.aspx?ID=1459)
- [Peshspine Grenade](https://2e.aonprd.com/Equipment.aspx?ID=549)
- [Twigjack Sack](https://2e.aonprd.com/Equipment.aspx?ID=1502)
- [Crystal Shards](https://2e.aonprd.com/Equipment.aspx?ID=685)

Now for the questions:

1. Does that mean poisons can be applied to these bomb and work on the primary target?
2. If yes would creatures injured by the splash damage also be affected by the poison?
3. Are there any other bombs with splash or piercing damage or ways to add such damage to a bomb?

Of course this would only useful until level 8 since from level 9 onwards typical bomber will switch to Quick Alchemy rather than prepared bombs.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### Bombs can be Poisoned

The rules for Injury poisons under [Method of Exposure](https://2e.aonprd.com/Rules.aspx?ID=709) of alchemical poisons covers this:

> **Injury**: An injury poison is activated by applying it to a weapon or ammunition, and it affects the target of the first Strike made using the poisoned item. If that Strike is a success and deals piercing or slashing damage, the target must attempt a saving throw against the poison. On a failed Strike, the target is unaffected, but the poison remains on the weapon and you can try again. On a critical failure, or if the Strike fails to deal slashing or piercing damage for some other reason, the poison is spent but the target is unaffected.

[Alchemical bombs](https://2e.aonprd.com/Rules.aspx?ID=703) are weapons so they can be poisoned just fine, and if the [Strike](https://2e.aonprd.com/Actions.aspx?ID=89) is a success and deals slashing or piercing damage then the target would be affected by the poison.

Creatures other than the target would not be affected by the poison according to the above, nor would the target be affected if the Strike was a failure (even if they still took slashing or piercing damage due to the splash).